# BigCommerce - BluePrint Issue - Product Options

Tags: bigcommerce

After creating custom product page in Blueprint and adding an option set with over 30 different options, I figured that the scss/js won't be applied to another product even if they use the same custom template, due to the fact that the only way to target each option is by using its ID. The template becomes no longer valid for another product, since the JS is targeting IDs that don't exist for the new product. Did the regular API call with the idea of copy/pasting product option ids from one product to another, but unfortunately the product option IDs are read-only. Any ideas ??? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey Samuil, what's your objective? Are you trying to find selectors that will work universally for all product options, so you can apply the same custom template to multiple products? It would be helpful to see the DOM so we can tell which classes are actually available.

Comment: Yes, Karen, that was my goal, but having the same option type multiple times for the same product prevented me from using the same class, since all of them have different style. That's why I used the IDs, but now the template is available for one product only.

Comment: Thanks for following up, Samuil. Do the other products share the same option set?

Comment: They are all using the same option set, but the problem here is that the options inside have different IDs for each product. Another problem was the fact that in Blue Print I had to have the original product page template hidden before the custom template, otherwise the page is breaking. This turned out to be even worse, when I had to use the IDs, because they were duplicated in the hidden template, so I replaced the initial IDs with custom ones, so I can use the original IDs from the custom template. Not sure if all that makes sense...

Comment: Not sure I follow :) Were you able to find a solution that worked for you in the end? I'd probably reach for something like using setAttribute to set a custom class on each option, since an element can only have a single ID.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I have over 30 options on the page (radio buttons & text fields), so their classes are duplicating, the only possible way for me to target them separately was using their IDs.